# Path problems with remote_api_stub

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_in_a_local_client) for using `remote_api_stub`.

I enter the following two lines in a Python shell:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine")
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
```

and then I get the error:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 76, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I can then add the path for yaml like this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")
```

but then I get another import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 95, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 25, in <module>
    import fancy_urllib
ImportError: No module named fancy_urllib
```

Is there an easy way to get everything I need on my path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. This is one of the more unloved corners of GAE (itself one of the more unloved corners of Google). Fortunately, `fancy_urllib` is the only other thing you'll need to manually add to your path.

I also like to make sure that the correct `google` is in the `PATH` before attempting to import remote_api_stub. You read that right -- Google has two different packages that can exist in the path as `google`.

Here's the important part of my module `init_remote_api`, which handles all the weirdness of setting up `remote_api`:

```
if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']

sys.path.append(GAE_PATH)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(GAE_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(GAE_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'))

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub

def auth_func():
    return (GAE_USERNAME, GAE_PASSWORD)

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,
                                   APP_DOMAIN)
```